# Nested Loop to generate a json array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have a requirement to enter two objects in a json array for each object in the input.

I wrote the following code to do so:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
var categoryList = ["Business","Authorization"]
---
payload map((payload01,indexOfPayload01)->
categoryList map((payload02,indexOfPayload02)->
    {
    "Name": payload01.Name,
    "Category":payload02,
    "Code":"Customer",
    "Percentage":null,
    "End Tag": "End"
    })
)
```

My output is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "Desc 1",
      "Category": "Business",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Desc 1",
      "Category": "Authorization",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Name": "Desc 2",
      "Category": "Business",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Desc 2",
      "Category": "Authorization",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    }
  ]
]
```

But I wanted the values as a single json array. Here the data was separated as two objects. My Expected output:

```
[
    {
      "Name": "Desc 1",
      "Category": "Business",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Desc 1",
      "Category": "Authorization",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Desc 2",
      "Category": "Business",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Desc 2",
      "Category": "Authorization",
      "Code": "Customer",
      "Percentage": null,
      "End Tag": "END"
    }
]
```

How can I get this done? Needless to say, I am new to Mule.

Thanks,
Anoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap as I'm showing in this example, or flatten the result as the example 2

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
var categoryList = ["Business","Authorization"]
---
payload flatMap((payload01,indexOfPayload01)->
categoryList map((payload02,indexOfPayload02)->
    {
    "Name": payload01.Name,
    "Category":payload02,
    "Code":"Customer",
    "Percentage":null,
    "End Tag": "End"
    })
)
```

This example shows how to use flattn

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
var categoryList = ["Business","Authorization"]
---
flatten(payload map((payload01,indexOfPayload01)->
categoryList map((payload02,indexOfPayload02)->
    {
    "Name": payload01.Name,
    "Category":payload02,
    "Code":"Customer",
    "Percentage":null,
    "End Tag": "End"
    })
))
```

Comment: Thanks machaval. Flatten was all that was missing.